# How to use Caesar Cypher encryption/decryption algorithm for UTF-8 character in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption

I have a small software that I developed in C++ Builder and I want to use the Caesar Cypher encryption/decryption algorithm to encrypt all data in text file, the problem is when I input data base on the UTF-8 like Arabic character some of chatterers become question mark like `?` when I decrypt the data. the following code just work in English characters so how to fix it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int i, x;
    char str[100];

    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    cin >> str;
    cout << "Please enter (1) for Encrypt and (2) for Decrypt\n";
    cin >> x;

    switch(x){
    case 1:
        for (i = 0 ; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0') ; i++)
            str[i] = str[i] + 2;
            cout << str;
        break;
    case 2:
        for (i = 0 ; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0') ; i++)
            str[i] = str[i] - 2;
            cout << str;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you might overflow/underflow and so have UB. Doing the modulo manually would solve that.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Can you give an example of broken input?

Comment: Arabic character for input:
علیرضانظری

The resutl of encryption:
فنAسظةوغسA

The result when the encrypted data has been passed to decrypt:
عل?رضانظر?

Comment: Those question mark `?` in the last above result just pointing me to one Arabic character `ی`.

Comment: @AlirezaNazari Can you [edit] that example into the body of your question.  Can you also include the UTF-8 encoding of the plain-text and the cipher-text.  (Also, try to make the sample shorter if you can)

Comment: @MartinBonner, I find the `utf8.h` but I don't now how to use it by now. https://github.com/sheredom/utf8.h

Comment: @AlirezaNazari I meant something like `for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) { cout << (int)str[i] << ' '; }`  If you could use the relevant manipulators to output the value in hex, that would be even better.

Comment: When you encrypt byte by byte the way you do, the resulting sequence of bytes is no longer a valid UTF-8 sequence. Then it doesn't print correctly on the terminal, and is likely mangled when you copy/paste it as text. Then, the sequence of bytes submitted for decryption is not the same sequence that was produced by encryption, so you don't get back the original string.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so that mean the process of encryption and decryption is current? what if before encrypting I convert the data to the binary and then encrypt them?

Comment: You do that already - you treat input data as binary. The problem is that you are trying to treat the output of the encryption as text, when it is not.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Thanks, I will test it with my software without console and with real data.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Please enter your first comment as answer I will select it.